# CodeIgniter on Heroku returns 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku, server, http-status-code-404

The default CodeIgniter (as you download it with the welcome controller and view) works fine locally and also on Heroku. However if I add the contents of this [official tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) it still works fine on my computer but not on Heroku anymore.

So this **works fine**:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

This **does not**:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Things I tried:

- Capitalizing first letter of controllers and models.
- Setting `$config['base_url']` to my full Heroku URL including protocol and trailing slash.
- Adding `url` to `$autoload['helper']` .
- `$config['uri_protocol']` is set to `REQUEST_URI`.

I do not use a custom `.htaccess`.

The index.php is run but it then only shows `404` pages. The `Pages controller` is never called.

Anyone with a clue?

Comment: It could be a htaccess issue but also make sure you have followed the codeigniter file name and class naming way. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git in Heroku: Git doesn't recognises file name case change by default.
Use

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Make file name first character Upper case and try.